# Passing instance of own class to another

Tags: c++, class, instance

Assuming I have these classes (question marks mark the question what I need to pass here):

```
class A
{
  ...
  public:
  void pass()
  {
     B ins;
     ins.doSth(?????);
  }
};

class B
{
  ...
  public:
  void doSth(const A &sth)
  {
    ...
  }
}

int main()
{
  A te;
  te.pass();
}
```

Can you pass an instance of your own class or is this just an example of a failed class structure on my side?

Comment: consider using `forward-declaration`. + implement the methods outside of the class after constructors to avoid using `incomplete type` compile-time error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current object in a member function is `*this`. You can pass that to another function.

You *will* have to consider how the classes depend on each other, and that one class cannot use the other class until the declaration is complete.

This would work though:

```
class A
{
  //...
  public:
  void pass();
};

class B
{
  //...
  public:
  void doSth(const A &sth)
  {
    //...
  }
};


// Here both classes are completely declared

void A::pass()
{
   B ins;
   ins.doSth(*this);
}


int main()
{
  A te;
  te.pass();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class "contains" an instance of each other so you'll face an error of undeclared types. To solve this issue you need to use forward declaration.

And you'll face another problem:

If your methods `doSth()` and `pass()` are defined inlinlely then you'll face a problem: "using incomplete types". The workaround  this is to implement these methods outside the class so that each object has been fully constructed before used.

The program may look like:

```
class A;
class B;

class A{
  public:
    void pass();
};

class B{
  public:
      void doSth(const A &sth){
  }
};

void A::pass(){
    B ins;
    ins.doSth(*this);
}

int main(){
  A te;
  te.pass();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the original code? I mean since the "B" instance is declared inside function definition block - which is processed in the second compilation pass - and not in the function signature or as a data member of  "A", It should actually compile.

Comment: @Red.Wave: I do get what you mean. But I only pointed to the OP if he/she face some stuff such as declaring a member data that couldn't compile.

Comment: I see. I just got suspicious about my memory.